# resizing with keras and tensorflow gives different results

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

code to reproduce error :

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=(7,7,256))

keras_resized = keras.backend.resize_images(inputs,224,224,data_format='channels_last',interpolation='bilinear')

tf_resized = tf.image.resize_bilinear(inputs,(224,224))
```

I have the following observations:

**1**. `tf_resized.get_shape()` gives:

> TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(224), Dimension(224), Dimension(256)])

which **is expected** result.

**2**. Where as `keras_resized.get_shape()` gives:

> TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(1568), Dimension(1568), Dimension(256)])

which is confusing.

**3**. but:

```
mean_input = keras.backend.mean(inputs, axis=[1,2], keepdims=True)
keras_resized = keras.backend.resize_images(mean_input,224,224,data_format='channels_last',interpolation='bilinear')
```

then `keras_resized.get_shape()` gives:

> TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(224), Dimension(224), Dimension(256)])

I need help to

- **how are the resizing methods different**
- **which is supposed to be used in which case**?
- **are case 1 and 3 equivalent**?

Comment: The fact that `7*224=1568` should help you on your way to the answer ;) the second and third parameters of `keras_resized.get_shape()` are multipliers of the original shape, not the output shape.

Answer (score 4):

According to my understanding there are two functions for resizing images in TF 2.0, 
namely:

```
tf.keras.backend.resize_images
tf.image.resize or tf.image.resize_images
```

Both functions has advantages and disadvantages.

For tf.keras.backend.resize_images

Advantages : supports different tensor channel orders (see data_format argument)
Disadvantages: images can only be upscaled by integer factor, but not downsize (as height_factor and width_factor must be a positive integer)

For tf.image.resize or tf.image.resize_images , 
Advantages are:
1)it supports different methods of interpolation like

```
ResizeMethod.BILINEAR: Bilinear interpolation
ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR: Nearest neighbor interpolation
ResizeMethod.BICUBIC: Bicubic interpolation
ResizeMethod.AREA: Area interpolation
```

2)Also, it supports image down scaling.

Depending upon the requirement you can use these methods

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't have to pass same parameters to both functions . For example if you want to go from 7 to 224 then with the tensorflow method you need to type :

```
tf.image.resize(inputs,(224,224))
```

but with the keras method you will have to specify the height_factor and width_factor : so in this case 224/7 = 32

```
tf.keras.backend.resize_images( image, 32, 32, data_format)
```